# Attaching base64 encoded file nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, soapui

I am trying to send a soap request with an attachment. Everything works fine except that the attachment i send is always of zero bytes. The soap server accepts a Base64 encoded file and i had achieved to do it in Java using the code

```
OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
outputStream.writeTo(fileOutputStream);
Base64.encode(outputStream.toByteArray())//argument passed to the function which sends this to the SOAP API
```

I want to replicate the same with node but i am unable to do so. Below is the function i am using to achieve this. I am reading some files from the client and trying to send it to the SOAP API. I have marked the place in the code responsible to read and append the data the rest is just for reference.

```
function createSoapEntryWithAtt(req,response){
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
        let filesArr = []
        for(objkeys in files){
            filesArr.push(files[objkeys])
        }
        return Promise.all(filesArr.map(item => {
            return new Promise((res,rej) => {
                var oldpath = item.path;
                var newpath = 'C:/user/' + item.name;
                **var data = fs.readFileSync(oldpath).toString('base64');
                let result = []
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2)// trying to create a 64bit byte array
                    result.push('0x' + data[i] + '' + data[i + 1])**

                console.log(result)
                if(data)
                    res({ [`${item.name}`]: result }) 
                rej("Error occured")
            })

        })).then(data => {
            let url = config.url
            var credentials = {
                AuthenticationInfo: {
                    userName: "user",
                    password: "passwd"
                }
            }
            let args = {
                Notes: "Testing From Node App",
            }
            let count = 0
            for (index in data) {
                if (count <= 3) {
                    **for(keys in data[index]){
                        //console.log(data[index][keys])
                        args[`Attachment${++count}_Name`] = keys
                       args[`Attachment${++count}_Data`] = data[index][keys]//Attaching the file read  
                    }
                }**
            }
            soap.createClient(url, function (err, client) {
                client.addSoapHeader(credentials)

                client.CreateWorkInfo(args, function (err, res) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Error is ----->" + err)
                    } else {
                        console.log("Response is -----> " + res)
                        response.end();
                    }
                })
            })

        })

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore this question .... and thanks and sorry if anyone wasted time on this question. The error was a careless mistake from my side in the line `args["Attachment${++count}_Name"] = keys
                       args["Attachment${++count}_Data"] = data[index][keys]`. Here as i am incrementing the count in both lines there is a mismatch in the sense that Attachment name will be 1 and then in the second line Attachment data will be 02 and hence the name does not contain any data.